# JQuery: Submiting data without the need of pressing the submit button?

Tags: jquery

```
$(function(){
   $("input[type=text]").keypress(function(){
        $("#loader").load("saveinputtodatabase.php", {...});
   });
});
```

This works fine on my code. It saves data on the database everytime the user types something on the input. But I know this isnt fair to the server because it will load many the same file many times, thus causing bandwidth to be used more than it should.

How can I make it load "saveinputtodatabase.php" only if 10 seconds has passed since the user has pressed a key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` for that.

```
$(function(){
  var timeout = 10000; // 10 seconds
  var tmt = null;
  $("input[type=text]").keypress(function() {
    if (tmt) clearTimeout(tmt);
    tmt = setTimeout(function() {   
      $("#loader").load("saveinputtodatabase.php", {...});
    }, timeout);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var timeout;
$('input[type=text]').keypress(function() {
    if(timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
    }    
    timeout = setTimeout(somefunc, 10000)
});
function somefunc() {
  $("#loader").load("saveinputtodatabase.php", {...});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
   $("input[type=text]").keypress(function(){
        var t=setTimeout(function(){
             $("#loader").load("saveinputtodatabase.php", {...})
        },10000);
   });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't do what was asked. Count of requests remains the same, all of them are just delayed.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$(function(){
   $("input[type=text]").keypress(function(){
    save();        
});
});
function save(){
setTimeout($("#loader").load("saveinputtodatabase.php", {...}),10000)
}
```

Comment: It doesn't do what was asked. Count of requests remains the same, all of them are just delayed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these underscore.js functions:

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#throttle

> Creates and returns a new, throttled version of the passed function,
>   that, when invoked repeatedly, will only actually call the original
>   function at most once per every wait milliseconds. Useful for
>   rate-limiting events that occur faster than you can keep up with.

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#debounce

> Creates and returns a new debounced version of the passed function
>   that will postpone its execution until after wait milliseconds have
>   elapsed since the last time it was invoked. Useful for implementing
>   behavior that should only happen after the input has stopped arriving.
>   For example: rendering a preview of a Markdown comment, recalculating
>   a layout after the window has stopped being resized, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('textarea').on('keyup', _.throttle(_.debounce(function() {
$.ajax(...);
}, 2000), 60000));
```

This will save your data as soon as the user stops typing for at least 2 seconds, but not more than once every minute.  checkout underscore.js for more info